# Can someone create a Nook tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I have insufficient rep to create a tag.  I'd like the Nook tag to be attached to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50625/nook-comics-on-ipad).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like this type of request on meta if it's not clear we even need a tag. If you can find a few questions between 3 and 8 that already could use the tag in question, please add them and we can also see about making it less likely that well target it for cleanup and deletion.

Comment: I would also like to thank you Keen for actually *using* the meta site! It's not often that we have new users here asking questions, or just new questions in general.

Comment: @daviesgeek I'm pretty familiar with SE. :)

Comment: @Keen Great! I just noticed you're a mod on SF/F, so that would explain it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [edited your question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/50625/revisions) to add [nook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nook) to the tags.

Comment: Good call, I'll do that in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: @Keen No problem!

Comment: @daviesgeek while your method would probably work in practice, a meta post requesting the tag is likely the "right" way to do it.

Comment: @DanielLawson I just realized that the meta site was probably the official way to do it.

Comment: @Keen See Daniel's comment.

Comment: Yup, I read it.